# How to write an Net::SMTP email in perl

Tags: perl, email, smtp

None of my hosts have any higher email modules, so I'd prefer to get this working without additional modules.

I've tried using google smtp servers (which i got working with \sendmail in XAMPP but never through Net::SMTP), I've tried secureserver.net smtp servers.  with and without SSL, with and without Hello lines, port 465 or 25.  Tried running from my local XAMPP server disabled all firewalls, tried running it remotely on goDaddy server.

Seems to be timing out and 'smtp failed'.  never getting to '...' even without the *unless($smtp)* test.  failing to get past auth, but since 'smtp failed' is being fired i assume its a problem with how i am forming the initial declaration of the object?  Though I've tried this in several different ways and I'm not getting any actual server errors.

```
my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($smtpserver,
    SSL => 1,                   
    Timeout => 60,
    Port => $smtpport,  # tried 25 and 465
    Debug => 1
);
    unless($smtp) { #tried with and without this
        print "smtp failed<br>[".$!."]<br>and<br>".$IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_ERROR;
    }
$smtp->auth($smtpuser, $smtppassword);    #nothing under this line is done
$smtp->mail($smtpuser);            #but i have checked and double checked the data
$smtp->recipient($recipi);         #pointed to several email addys but never arrive
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("From: $smtpuser");
$smtp->datasend("To: $recipi");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: test mail ver six sm loc 12"); 
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("blah blah");
$smtp->dataend();
$smtp->quit;
print"...";  #never gets printed
```

Any suggestions welcome, the only thing I've thought of and *not* tried is including the authentication in the initial object deceleration, i can find no where that shows how to do that.

edit; added *$! and $IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_ERROR* Steffen suggested the result is $! = [Bad file descriptor] and $IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_ERROR returns nothing.

Comment: Please include `$!` and `$IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_ERROR` in your `print "smtp failed<br>"` to get details of the error. And since you`ve already used `Debug` please include the actual debug output in your question. Also `SSL =>1` makes only sense with port 465, for ports 25 and 587 you need to use `$smtp->starttls()` instead.

Comment: Updated my post with your suggestion, port 25 without ssl times out, [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond] on both servers.   unsure how to use starttls, what args do i () into this?

Comment: *"port 25 without ssl times out,..."* - this suggests that either there is no service on this port on the target host or that your connection is blocked by a firewall (which seems to be not unusual in GoDaddy setups to prevent spammers). If the initial connection already fails `starttls` will not help. As to how to use `starttls` please refer to the documentation of Net::SMTP.

Comment: thanks, i skimmed IO::Socket::SSL docs so i think i understand starttls a bit better.  On port 465 with ssl=>1 i get $![Bad file descriptor] i'm guessing that's a problem with the initial object setup?

Comment: Yes, I would say that the initial TCP connection fails already.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code (it requires Authen::SASL module which might be not part of your setup)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use Net::SMTP 3.0;
use Authen::SASL qw(Perl);

my $sender = my $user = 'your_id@gmail.com';
my $password = 'your_password';
my $receiver = 'your_receiver@gmail.com';

my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new(
    'smtp.gmail.com',
    SSL=>1,
    Timeout => 20,
    Debug   => 1,
);

die "Initialization failed: $!" if !defined $smtp;

print "Trying to authenticate..";
$smtp->auth( $user, $password) or die "could not authenticate\n";

my $header = 
"To: $receiver
From: $sender
Content-Type: text/html
Subject: Testing Net::SMTP

";

my $body = "
The <i>body</i> of the <b>email</b> Net-SMTP example
";

$smtp->mail( $sender );
$smtp->to( $receiver );
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend( $header );
$smtp->datasend( $body );
$smtp->datasend( '' );
$smtp->dataend();
$smtp->quit();
```

Comment: I don't have Authen::SASL, but i installed it on my local XAMPP server to try your code, I'm not getting anything, no [Trying to authenticate..] and no [Initialization failed:], and no email.

Comment: I just verified the script, the test email was delivered to my Gmail mailbox. Now I should ask you an obvious question: Did you put into the script proper $sender, $password, $receiver? **Note:** the script was tested under **Straberry Perl** (http://strawberryperl.com/).

Comment: Reinstalled the latest Strawberry Perl I'm still not getting anything from this script, if i comment out [SSL=>1,] and add [Port => 587,] it prints [Trying to authenticate..] but nothing after the authentication line not even the fail code or any prints i add after there.  I think google needs SSL but somehow my system is failing when calling it, or blocking ports, though i am able to get to google smtp through my sendmail setup I see it uses port 587 and probably TLS..  i tried installing Net::SMTP::TLS but it fails [could not expand Net::SMTP::TLS].

Comment: What debug output information from script states? There should be _MAIL CODES_, have you looked what they mean? Are you sure that sent email did not get into **spam** folder?

Answer (score 2):

[Authen::SASL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Authen::SASL) (last updated 2012) seems to be not needed these days. I'm not sure why.

This code sufficed to send to Gmail:

```perl
use v5.32;
use warnings;
use Net::SMTP;

my %smtp = (
  host => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  from     => '', # also: user
  password => q(),     # app password: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833
  to       => '',
  subject  => 'Net::SMTP: Hello',
);

my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($smtp{host},
  SSL   => 1,
  Debug => 1,
);

$smtp->auth($smtp{from}, $smtp{password});;

my $header = <<"HEADER";
To: $smtp{to}
From: $smtp{from}
Content-Type: text/html
Subject: $smtp{subject}
HEADER

my $body = <<"BODY";
The <i>body</i> of the <b>email</b> Net-SMTP example
BODY

$smtp->mail($smtp{from}); # SMTP: MAIL FROM
$smtp->to($smtp{to}); # SMTP: RCPT TO

$smtp->data(); # SMTP: DATA
$smtp->datasend($header);
$smtp->datasend($body);
$smtp->dataend(); # SMTP: .

$smtp->quit(); # SMTP: QUIT
```

This is a modification of the previous answer with method-explaining comments, and without excessive code such as the SSL module and `datasend` with empty string.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I needed to create an app password for gmail. This took just a couple of minutes. Thank you!

Comment: The only correction is about headers:

my $header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8' . "\r\n"; 
$header .= "To: $receiver\n";
$header .= "Subject: Test message\n";

Comment: I wonder why you thought `Authen::SASL` is no longer needed... There's a [check](https://github.com/steve-m-hay/perl-libnet/blob/v3.15/lib/Net/SMTP.pm#L164-L167) in the `auth()` method. But yeah, it doesn't die right away. Before 2009 it [did](https://github.com/steve-m-hay/perl-libnet/commit/e17d933dae162eb2ce11b5f6787c21bc360c88e5#diff-035404fddc756a449ebf5a68bc5fb09d87f539718fe36fc6adc8817f19e9a853L112-R115). Maybe that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```perl
use Net::SMTP::SSL;

my $smtp = Net::SMTP::SSL->new(
    Host=>$host,
    Hello=>$host,
    Port=>465,
    Debug=>1
);

$smtp->auth($smtp_user, $smtp_pass);

# ...
```

Comment: CPAN module: https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP::SSL

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this. Not sure if my dependencies are low enough. [`IO::Socket::SSL`](https://github.com/steve-m-hay/perl-libnet/blob/v3.15/lib/Net/SMTP.pm#L24-L30), [`MIME::Base64` and `Authen::SASL`](https://github.com/steve-m-hay/perl-libnet/blob/v3.15/lib/Net/SMTP.pm#L164-L167) are dependencies of `Net::SMTP`. `Email::Simple`... I think it's a bit simpler with this module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SMTP;
use Email::Simple;

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
    header => [
      From => 'me@example.com',
      To => 'me@gmail.com',
      Subject => 'test email',
    ],
    body => 'test body (perl)',
);

my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new('mail.example.com',
    SSL => 1,
    Debug => 1);
$smtp->auth('me@example.com', '...')
    or die join', ', $!, $smtp->code, $smtp->message;
$smtp->mail('me@example.com');
$smtp->to('me@gmail.com');
$smtp->data($email->as_string);
$smtp->quit;
```

If you want explicit TLS:

```
--- a.pl    2023-10-06 06:15:32.617525652 +0300
+++ b.pl    2023-10-06 06:16:18.681293590 +0300
@@ -13,8 +13,9 @@
 );
 
 my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new('mail.example.com',
-    SSL => 1,
+    Port => 587,
     Debug => 1);
+$smtp->starttls;
 $smtp->auth('me@example.com', '...')
     or die join', ', $!, $smtp->code, $smtp->message;
 $smtp->mail('me@example.com');
```

More complete repro [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/ec029cea9f8ca7d3c6df9cf56a276b7c).